# How to execute a script on a remote machine?

Tags: shell

I would like to know how i can execute a script remotly(on another machine). I dont know what kind of platform that gonna be. So Please also suggest me what kind of scripts i should prefer.

Comment: @downvote... when you downvote then stackoverflow ask you to mention why you downvoted...

Comment: @downvoters... i dont know why people downvote without teling the reason.. they dont know how to use stackoverflow... just misusing the rights... atleast i should be familiar what mistake i did so that i can explain them somthing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to script or use Java?

You can, for instance, use shell scripts and execute other shell scripts remotely via ssh. You can also execute Java code out of the shell scripts.

On Linux, FreeBSD and MacOS, you have good shells and ssh pre-installed. On Windows, you can for instance use Cygwin to get them.

Comment: Ok, then my answer should be suitable.

Comment: just secureCopy any shell script to the remote machine, open an ssh connection and execute it on the remote machine. See e.g. here: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-ssh-in-unix-or-linux-shell-script/

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways... for instance:

```
$ ssh user@host /bin/sh </local/path/to/script
```

Comment: @CiaranG: that runs a shell on the remote host passing the script to be executed via stdin

Comment: A shell? What is stdin? I'm totally not getting this. What you posted, is this a DOS script, PowerShell, I can't tell.

Comment: @CiaranG: this is just Unix/Linux/C lingo, Wikipedia is your friend: [shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29), [stdin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdin#Standard_input_.28stdin.29), [script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Script_%28computing%29), [sh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell), [ssh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)...